# PHP lack of 'undefined' type workaround

Tags: php

Lets say I have a class

```
class Animal {
    public $name;
    public $group;
}
```

Then I do:

```
$animal = new Animal;
$animal->name = 'mouse';
```

How can I determine that $group was not set and not just NULL?

Sometimes the value will be NULL intentionally an I need to know either way. Annoyingly PHP doesn't seem to have an undefined type and isset() returns false even if the value is set to NULL.

Any ideas?

Comment: `empty()` may be the droid you're looking for

Comment: @treyBake `empty()` is even more ambiguous than `isset()`. `int 0` (amongst others) will return true on empty

Comment: @Martin is that a bug? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php says that would be empty?

Comment: Why would you use `NULL` to have any other meaning than "unset"?

Comment: @treyBake No, perhaps you misunderstand. `empty()` *might* give the desired result but it **will** also give false positives, such as `(int)0`

Comment: @Martin huh, never noticed that before o.O maybe I've been lucky .. will keep an eye on that in the future though, thanks :)

Comment: @mbj in my case i am deserialising a partial API resource response. I need to know when a property is NULL or not set at all.

Comment: You can distinguish between *object doesn't have this property* and *property value is `null`*. There's no *property exists but has "no" value.*

Comment: You could have your constructor initialise the values to "impossible" values and use that as an indication of "not set".

Comment: @Martin That is incomplete and incorrect. It only behaves that way in that example because the property is `protected` and `__isset` hasn't been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to distinguish those. The default value for "no value" is `null`, and there's indeed no *other* "no value" value. You should initialise your values with type-appropriate defaults, like `0` for integers. Where that's not possible, you shouldn't need to have to distinguish between "not initialised" and "no value", as those should be synonymous (that is, as far as PHP is concerned; if you have a case where you do need to distinguish those, you need some other workaround).

Comment: to add to this answer: `the value will be NULL intentionally` is what should be changed.

Comment: A value being `null` intentionally may be perfectly appropriate.

Comment: In our case it is appropriate to set the value to NULL.

Comment: In this case it clearly is not. If there is a meaningful difference between the value being NULL because it was set to that and it being NULL because it never was set, it is not appropriate. Just define some constant with an appropriate name and use that.

Comment: @blues I think you might be right in using a constant and then just look for that. In my case I am updating database records using the deserialised object. If a value is NULL then it will over write the existing value in the database which may not be the intention.

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use a pre-defined class, deserialize your data into array or stdClass like json_decode does.

```
$json = '{"name":"mouse","group":null}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump(property_exists($obj, 'group')); #true
var_dump(property_exists($obj, 'group2')); #false

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump(array_key_exists('group', $arr)); #true
var_dump(array_key_exists('group2', $arr)); #false
```

---

You can also wrap the result into your class

```
class Animal
{
    private $obj;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->obj->{$name};
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->obj) && property_exists($this->obj, $name);
    }
}

$animal = new Animal;
var_dump(isset($animal->group));
```

Comment: Even the value of group is NULL, property_exists/array_key_exists returns true, because they are exist.

Comment: I use type hinting in my code so i need to deserialise it to a specific class.

Comment: @user1094128 It's not a problem